# Limit of $f$ at $(0,0)$ vs limits of $f(x,kx)$ when $x\to0$

Tags: real-analysis

Why if for all $k\in\mathbb R$ we have $f(x,kx)\to\ell$ when $x\to 0$ then this is not enough to conclude that $f(x,y)\to\ell$ if $(x,y)\to (0,0)$?

Indeed, if the limit is the same when we can consider all straight lines that pass through $(0,0)$, logically it should be enough to conclude on the limit, but I found a counter example. So why doesn't it work ? What is the mathematical reason behind this phenomenon?

Comment: because each straight line is independent from the rest?

Comment: and what about $f(x, x^2)$?

Comment: To expand on @user251257's comment (which exactly sums up the problem), consider the wedge $|y|<x^2$, then every straight  line $y=kx$ with $k\ne0$ leaves this wedge strictly before reaching $(0,0)$ hence the limits of $f(x,kx)$ when $x\to0$, for $k\ne0$, say nothing about the behaviour of $f$ in the wedge near $(0,0)$. (To get rid of the case $k=0$, consider the half wedge $0<y<x^2$ and adapt the argument.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're only looking at linear/straight lines, while there are other, non-linear ways to reach $(0,0)$. Think of it in terms of speed:

if you look at $(x,x)\rightarrow (0,0)$, both entries will get near to $0$ simultaneously. If you look at $(x,kx)$, this will still happen "quite simultaneously", meaning that the factor $k$ will not affect it very much .

Now let's change that to $(x,x^2)$, then $x^2$ will get closer to $0$ much faster than $x$. Just pluck in some numbers, for $x=\frac{1}{10}$ we have $x^2=\frac{1}{100}$, for $x=\frac{1}{100}$ we have $x^2=\frac{1}{10000}$.

This becomes even more obvious, when you look at e.g. $(x,e^{-\frac{1}{x}})$, as $e^{-\frac{1}{x}}$ will get closer to $0$ **much** faster than $x$ (for example we have $x=\frac{1}{100},e^{-100}\approx 3.7\times 10^{-44}$).

Answer (score 3):

For a counterexample, let $f(x,y)=\frac{x^2y}{x^4+y^2}$. Then $f(x,kx)=\frac{kx^3}{x^4+k^2x^2}=\frac{kx}{x^2+k^2}\to 0$ as $x\to 0$. But $f(x,x^2)=\frac{x^4}{2x^4}=\frac{1}{2}\not\to 0$

The idea is that $y$ can approach $0$ faster than $x$ can by a LOT, giving issues.

Answer (score -1):

For a function in more than one  variable;

For limit of a  function $f$   to exist at a particular point we have to consider all possible paths for reaching that point and see whether the limit exits or not. What you are considering are only  the straight line paths.

There can be many ways to reach that point

Comment: This is not really my question. I know that, but by considering all straight line, it looks logical that I consider all path because all straight line will recover all paths.

Comment: How does a straight line cover all paths? I dont know that really