# Help me show that the limit $\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)}\frac{2e^x y^2}{x^2+y^2}$ does not exist

Tags: calculus, limits

> Show that the limit $\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)}\frac{2e^x y^2}{x^2+y^2}$
>   does not exist

$$\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)}\frac{2e^x y^2}{x^2+y^2}$$

Divide by $y^2$:

$$\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)}\frac{2e^x}{\frac{x^2}{y^2}+1}$$

$$=\frac{2(1)}{\frac{0}{0}+1}$$

Since $\frac{0}{0}$ is undefined. This limit does not exist.

**I am not satisfied with my proof.** Makes me think that what I just did was simple step, and not acceptable university level mathematics. Any comments on my proof?

Comment: Try study $\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)}\frac{2x y^2}{x^2+y^2}$. This time the limit exists.

Comment: Just to say $\frac00$ is not enough. It may exist, may not. You need to resolve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed your proof is not valid.

Let $y=x$, $\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)}\frac{2e^x y^2}{x^2+y^2}=1$

Let $y=2x$, $\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)}\frac{2e^x y^2}{x^2+y^2}=\large{8\over5}$

So it cannot exist.

Comment: Why cannot it exist according to your proof? Cause $2x \neq x$ so why should $\frac{8}{5}=1$ ?

Comment: When a limit exist you need it exist on all path and the values of all those limits be equal. When you take the path with slope $2$ and when you take the path with slope $1$ the limits are not equal so a general limits cannot exist.

Comment: +1 Oh I see :) But doesn't changing the path also change the function we are evaluating the limit of? So, why does the limit of two different function must equal the same?

Comment: A multi-variable function has more dimensions than a single-variable function, With two variable, we are working inside the three dimensional space, A path represent a two-dimensional line so you are not changing the function but talking about a specific part of the function. All the lines must go to the same point for a limit at the point to exist.

Comment: Oh I understand now, thanks for coming back and helping me.

Answer (score 1):

If we let $(x,y)\to(0,0)$ on the $x$ axis we have
$$f(x,0)=\frac{2e^x(0)^2}{x^2+(0)^2}=0\quad\implies \quad f(x,y)\to0\quad\text{as } (x,y)\to(0,0)\text{ on the }x\text{ axis}$$
On the $y$ axis we have
$$f(0,y)=\frac{2e^0y^2}{0^2+y^2}=2\quad\implies \quad f(x,y)\to 2\quad\text{as } (x,y)\to(0,0)\text{ on the }y\text{ axis}$$

Comment: +1 Oh I understand :) Thanks alot

Answer (score 0):

The limit exists if for any $\varepsilon>0$ there exists a $\delta>0$ such that
$$\frac{2e^x y^2}{x^2+y^2}<\varepsilon\tag 1$$
if the distance of $(x,y)$ from the origin is less than $\delta$. That is, the limit exists only if it is independent of the path of $(x,y)$ when approaching $(0,0)$.

In the case of functions of one variable the parallel statement is that the limit exits if the  following two limits exist and equal

$$\lim_{x\downarrow 0}f(x)=\lim_{x\uparrow 0}f(x).$$

---

I am going to show that in the case of the limit at stake $(1)$ is not satisfied.

So far so good:

$$\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)}\frac{2e^x y^2}{x^2+y^2}=\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)}\frac{2e^x}{\frac{x^2}{y^2}+1}.$$

At this point, however, let's say that $y=mx$, that is, $(x,y)$ approaches $(0,0) $along the line $y=mx$. Substituting this, we get

$$\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)}\frac{2e^x}{\frac{1}{m^2}+1}=\frac{2}{\frac1{m^2}+1}.$$

The limit does not exist because its value depends on the path we approach the origin.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the answers showing you a way: when dealing with limits you can't just put in the values for (in this case) $x$ and $y$. With the same argument you would say, that $$\lim\limits_{x\to 0} \frac{\sin(x)}{x}=\frac{0}{0}=\text{undefined}$$ whereas it is easy to show (and something one should know) that $$\lim\limits_{x\to 0} \frac{\sin(x)}{x}=1.$$ Just saying that $\frac{0}{0}$ is undefined is not enough, the limit might still exist. With more than one variable this becomes even more complicated as there are "more ways" to approach $(0,0)$.

You also might find [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1368429/limit-of-f-at-0-0-vs-limits-of-fx-kx-when-x-to0/1368477#1368477) helpful.